# Number of coefficients equal to $k$ in certain "Fibonacci polynomials"

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_i$ denote the $i$th Fibonacci number (with $F_1=F_2=1$). Define
$$ P_n(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1+x^{F_{i+1}}). $$
Let $\nu_k(n)$ denote the number of coefficients of the polynomial $P_n(x)$
that are equal to the positive integer $k$. Evidence suggests that for
sufficiently large $n$ (depending on $k$), $\nu_k(n)$ is a linear
polynomial in $n$. These polynomials for $1\leq k\leq 12$ are
empirically given by $2n$, $4n-8$, $8n-32$, $12n-68$, $16n-112$,
$24n-192$, $24n-224$, $36n-352$, $40n-432$, $48n-544$, $40n-512$, and
$88n-1056$. How can one prove these observations and generalize to any
$k$? Similar conjectures can be made for a wide class of more
general polynomials. See my papers https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04647
and https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02131 for some related results. The
linear algebraic techniques in these papers might be applicable to
the present problem.

**Addendum.** The case $k=1$ follows easily from properties of the Fibonacci triangle poset discussed in Section 3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02131.

Comment: Not sure if this work [REPRESENTATIONS BY COMPLETE SEQUENCES — PART I (FIBONACCI) V,E. HOGGATT,JR. and S.L. BASIN, FIBONACCI BIBLIOGRAPHICAL AND RESEARCH CENTER, SAN JOSE STATE COLLEGE](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~giacomo.dellariccia/Glossary/recurrence%20relations/Hoggatt,%20Jr.Basin1963.pdf) (Fibonacci Quarterly 1963 (1,3): 1-14) related to computation of the coefficients of $P_n(x)$ might help or not.

Comment: @BillyJoe: I took a look but don't see how to use their results.

Comment: It looks like for $k\geq 2$ the $n$ argument in the linear functions is off by 1. For example, for $k=2$ instead of $4n-8$ it should be $4(n-1)-8 = 4n-12$; for $k=3$ it should be $8(n-1)-32 = 8n-40$, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will use the set up of [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/266215) to a previous question about "Fibonacci polynomials".

The key observation is that the coefficient of $x^m$ in $P(x)$ equals the number of "unrollings" of the Zeckendorf representation $Z_m$ (viewed as a $01$-string) of $m$, where any substring $001$ can be unrolled into $110$. Let $U(Z_m)$ denote the number of such unrollings. It is easy to see that
$$U(0^p1v) = U(v) + \left\lfloor\frac{p}2\right\rfloor U(0v).$$

Then one can notice that
$$\nu_k(n) = \nu'_k(n) + \nu'_k(n-1) - [k=1],$$ where $\nu'_k(n)$ is the number of coefficients of $x^m$ in $P(x)$ equal $k$ with $m<F_{n+2}$ (ie. $|Z_m|\leq n$). Here the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) $[k=1]$ eliminates double counting of $v=0^n$ and $v=0^{n-1}$, which both correspond to $m=0$ .

The aforementioned recurrence for $U$ allows us to obtain one for $\nu'_k(n)$ as follows.

Let $a_1(n,k)$ be the number of strings $v$ of length $n$ starting with 0 such that $U(v)=k$, and let $a_2(n,k_1,k_2)$ be the number of strings $v$ of length $n$ starting with 0 such that $U(v)=k_1$ and $U(0v)=k_2$. Clearly, $a_2(n,k_1,k_2)=0$ whenever $k_1>k_2$ and we find it convenient to assume that both $a_1$ and $a_2$ are zero for $n<0$. Then we have
$$\nu'_k(n) = a_1(n,k) + a_1(n-1,k),$$
where the terms enumerate $v$ starting with 0 and 1, respectively. The count $a_1$ satisfies the recurrence:
\begin{split}
a_1(n,k) &= [k=1] + a_1(n-2,k) \\
&+ \sum_{p=2}^{2k-1}  \sum_{k_2 = \lceil k/(1+c_p)\rceil}^{\lfloor (k-1)/c_p\rfloor} a_2(n-1-p,k-c_pk_2,k_2),
\end{split}
where $p$ runs over the possible lengths of the initial run of 0's in $v$, the first term corresponds to $v=0^n$ and the second term corresponds to $p=1$, and $c_p:=\left\lfloor\frac{p}2\right\rfloor$. Finally, the count $a_2$ satisfies the recurrence:
\begin{split}
&a_2(n,k_1,k_2) = [(k_1,k_2)=(1,1)] \\
&+ [k_1=k_2]\cdot\sum_{c=1}^{k_1-1} \sum_{t = \lceil k_1/(1+c)\rceil}^{\lfloor (k_1-1)/c\rfloor} a_2(n-1-2c,k_1-ct,t) \\
& + [k_1<k_2]\cdot a_2(n-1-(2\lfloor \tfrac{k_1-1}{k_2-k_1}\rfloor+1),  (k_1-1) \bmod (k_2-k_1) + 1,k_2-k_1),
\end{split}
where the terms correspond to $v=0^n$, even $p>0$, and odd $p>0$, respectively.

---

**Example $k=1$.** In this case we have $a(n,1) = 1 + a_1(n-2,1)$, implying that $a_1(n,1)=1+\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$. Then $a_2(n,0,1) = 0$ and $a_2(n,1,1) = 1$. It follows that $\nu'_1(n) = n+1$ and $\nu_1(n) = 2n$.

**ADDED.** It can be seen that $a_2(n,k_1,k_2)$ stabilizes as $n$ grows and its limit $\bar a_2(k_1,k_2)$ satisfies the recurrence:
\begin{split}
&\bar a_2(k_1,k_2) = [(k_1,k_2)=(1,1)] \\
&+ [k_1=k_2]\cdot \sum_{c=1}^{k_1-1} \sum_{t = \lceil k_1/(1+c)\rceil}^{\lfloor (k_1-1)/c\rfloor} \bar a_2(k_1-ct,t) \\
& + 
[k_1<k_2]\cdot \bar a_2( (k_1-1) \bmod (k_2-k_1) + 1, k_2-k_1).
\end{split}
Then it is easy to find the coefficient $q_k$ of $n$ in the linear formula for $\nu_k(n)$ (which is the quadruple of such coefficient in $a_1(n,k)$) as
$$q_k = 2[k=1] + 4\sum_{c=1}^{k-1}  \sum_{k_2 = \lceil k/(1+c)\rceil}^{\lfloor (k-1)/c\rfloor} \bar a_2(k-ck_2,k_2).$$
Here are the values of $q_k$ for $k\leq 30$:

```
2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 24, 24, 36, 40, 48, 40, 88, 48, 72, 96, 108, 64, 152, 72, 176, 144, 120, 88, 312, 144, 144, 200, 264, 112, 416
```

There seems to be no easier way to get the free term of $\nu_k(n)$ than computing it as $\nu_k(n) - q_kn$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: This is an excellent solution. There should be more general results
for which a different method is needed. One random example: define
$G_0=1$, $G_1=3$, $G_i=2G_{i-1}+2G_{i-2}$ for $i\geq 2$. Let $P_n(x)
= \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(1+x^{G_i}+x^{2G_i}\right)$. Let $f_k(n)$ be the
number of coefficients of $P_n(x)$ equal to $k$. Then empirically
$\sum_{n\geq 0}f_1(n)x^n = (1+x^2)/(1-x)(1-2x-x^2)$, $\sum_{n\geq
0}f_2(n)x^n = 2x^3(1+x)^2/(1-2x-x^2)^2$, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a `formulas-free' version of the proof that the numbers $\nu_k(n)$ are indeed linear in $n$, for a fixed $k$ and large enough $n\geq n_0(k)$. The following lemma is the same as Max Alekseyev's starting point. As in his answer, we assume that the Zeckendorf representation is a $01$-string, where the leftmost digit is the least impotrant one.

**Lemma.** Each representation of a positive integer $M$ as a sum of distinct Fibonacci numbers is obtained from the Zeckendorf representation of $M$ by *unrollings* of the form $001\mapsto 110$.

*Proof.* Clearly, all unrollings produce representations of $M$.

Conversely, we show that each representation (also viewed as a $01$-string) can be rolled to the Zeckendorf representation by the operations $110\mapsto 001$. Take an arbitrary representation. Find the rightmost occurrence of $11$; it is followed by $0$ (or by the end of line, in which case we just augment the string by $0$ on the right). Replace this $110$ with $001$ and repeat.

This process stops, as the sum of elements in the string decreases. At the end, we get a string without occurrences of $11$, i.e., the Zeckendorf representation of $M$.  $\Box$

Now let the Zeckendorf representation of $M$ have the form $0^{i_p}10^{i_{p-1}}1\dots 0^{i_1}1$, where $i_p\geq 0$ and $i_t>0$ for $1\leq t<p$. Assume that $M$ has exactly $k$ representations.

**1.** We have $i_t\leq 2k-1$ for all $t$. Indeed, if $i:=i_t\geq 2k$, then we can make the sequence of unrollings
$$
  0^i1\mapsto 0^{i-2}110\mapsto 0^{i-4}11010\mapsto\dots\mapsto
  0^{i-2k}1(10)^k,
$$
obtaining $k+1$ distinct representations, which cannot appear.

**2.** We have $i_t\leq1$ for all $t\geq k$ (thus $i_t=1$ for $p<t\leq k$ and $i_p\in\{0,1\}$ if $p\geq k$). Indeed, if $i_t>1$, then we can successively unroll the $t$th rightmost $1$, then the $(t-1)$th rightmost $1$, and so on, again obtaining at least $k+1$ distinct representations.

The two properties above show that the Zeckendorf representations of all numbers $M$  under consideration look like either $0101\dots01 $ or $1010\dots 1$ followed by a tail with bounded number of $1$s and bounded number of $0$s between consecutive $1$s. Moreover, the number of representations of such tail is still $n$, as the unrollings cannot touch the starting periodical part. There are finitely many such tails.

In other words, $\nu_k(n)$ can be computed  as follows. There are finitely many possible tails corresponding to numbers having $k$ representations and having the form $10^{i_p}1\dots 0^{i_1}1$, where $i_k\geq 2$. Each of those can be augmented by a periodic string of the form $\dots 01010$. in order to produce a string of length at most $n$. The number of such strings is $\nu_k(n)$.

Now it is clear that this number is linear in $n$ for all sufficiently large $n\geq n_0$ (where $n_0$ is the largest length of the tail).