# A conjectured rational generating function

Tags: co.combinatorics, generating-functions, recurrences

In regard to my question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430741), let $G_n$
be a sequence of positive integers satisfying
$\lim_{n\to\infty}G_n=\infty$, such that the generating function
$\sum_{n\geq 1} G_nx^n$ is rational. Let
$$ P_n(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1+x^{G_i}\right), $$
or even more generally,
$$ P_n(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n \left( 1+x^{G_i}+x^{2G_i}+\cdots +
     x^{rG_i}\right) $$
for some postive integer $r$ (independent from $n$). (Maybe even more
general products are
possible.) For a positive integer $k$, let $\nu_k(n)$ be the number of
coefficients of the polynomial $P_n(x)$ that are equal to $k$. Is the
generating function $F(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\nu_k(n)x^n$ rational? If so, what
can be said about it? If $F(x)$ is not always rational, for what
$G_n$ is it rational?

Comment: The condition that $\lim_{n\to\infty}G_n=\infty$ may be unnecessary.

Comment: Regarding your last comment: for example it is clearly true in the "Pascal's triangle" case of $G_i=1 \; \forall i$.