# Counting monomials modulo prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

The present quest emanates from [this study](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.02131.pdf) by R. Stanley, including his [recent MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430741/number-of-coefficients-equal-to-k-in-certain-fibonacci-polynomials). Define the product (polynomials after full expansion)
$$I_n(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+x^{F_{i+1}})$$
based on the Fibonacci numbers $F_n$ with $F_1=F_2=1$. My focus is on the sequence $c_p(n)$, which enumerates the number of monomials, in $I_n(x)$, having non-zero coefficients modulo a prime $p$.

For example, if $p=2$ then $c_2(n)$ starts with $2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 20, 32, 48, 72, 112, \dots$. One may readily translate this problem to counting monomials in the product $\prod_{i=1}^n(1-x^{F_{i+1}})$ (see [OEIS A104767](https://oeis.org/A104767)) whose coefficients are $-1, 0, 1$ (see [this paper](https://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/46_47-1/Zhao_12-08.pdf)).

> **QUESTION.** Given a prime $p$, is it true that the generating function $\sum_{n\geq1}c_p(n)y^n$ is a rational function?

**Examples.** We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\geq1}c_2(n)y^n &=\frac{2y+2y^3}{1-2y+2y^2-2y^3}, \\
\sum_{n\geq1}c_3(n)y^n &=\frac{2y+3y^3+4y^5}{1-2y+2y^2-3y^3+4y^4-4y^5}, \\
\sum_{n\geq1}c_5(n)y^n &=\frac{2y+y^3+3y^5+4y^7}{1-2y+y^2-y^3+2y^4-3y^5+4y^6-4y^7}.
\end{align}

Comment: An affirmative answer follows from Theorem 6.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.02131.pdf. For some related open problems, see Conjectures 6.2 and 6.3.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you.