# Fibonacci and product polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

The motivation for my current question arises from [this MO post by R. Stanley](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430741/number-of-coefficients-equal-to-k-in-certain-fibonacci-polynomials). *Caveat.* There's a slight alteration.
With the convention $F_1=F_2=1$ for the Fibonacci numbers, define the polynomials $f_n(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+x^{F_i})$.

For a given prime $p$, expand $f_n(x)$ and compute the coefficients modulo $p$. Denote the resulting polynomial by $g_{n,p}(x)$ and its number of non-zero coefficients by $N(g_{n,p})$.

**Example.** $g_{1,2}=1+x, g_{2,2}=1+x^2, g_{3,2}=1+x^4, g_{4,2}=1+x^3+x^4+x^7$, we find that
$N(g_{1,2})=2, N(g_{2,2})=2, N(g_{3,2})=2, g_{4,2}=4$. I like to propose two sets of questions.

> **QUESTION 1.** Are any of these recurrences true?
> \begin{align}
> N(g_{n,2})&=2N(g_{n-1,2})-2N(g_{n-2,2})+2N(g_{n-3,2}), \\
> N(g_{n,3})&=2N(g_{n-1,3})-2N(g_{n-2,3})+3N(g_{n-3,3})-4N(g_{n-4,3})+4N(g_{n-5,3}), \\
> N(g_{n,5})&=2N(g_{n-1,5})-N(g_{n-2,5})+N(g_{n-3,5})-2N(g_{n-4,5})+3N(g_{n-5,5}) \\
> & \qquad \qquad \qquad-4N(g_{n-6,5})+4N(g_{n-7,3}).
> \end{align}

> **QUESTION 2.** For fixed prime $p$, does the sequence $\{N(g_{n,p})\}_{n\geq1}$ have a rational generating function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 2 follows from Theorem 6.1 of [arXiv:2101.02131](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.02131.pdf). (In this reference, I consider $\prod_{i=1}^n(1+x^{F_{i+1}})$ rather than $\prod_{i=1}^n(1+x^{F_i})$, but the proof still works.) The result holds for any positive integer $p$, not just primes. The proof is constructive, so in principle one can obtain actual recurrences.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.